# How to calculate the derivative of logarithm of a matrix?

Tags: matrices, differential-operators

Given a square matrix $M$, we know the exponential of $M$ is
$$\exp(M)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{M^n}{n!}}$$

and the logarithm is $$\log(M)=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(I-M)^k}{k}$$

The derivative of $\exp(M)$ should be itself. It is easy to prove if $\frac{dM}{M}=I$.

But how to calculate the derivative of $\log(M)$? By the same way of calculation of the derivative of $\exp(M)$, the derivative of $\log(M)$ cannot converge.

So what is the derivative of $\log(M)$?

Comment: One thing to note is that while the series for $\exp(M)$ converges for any complex square matrix $M$, the series you give for $\log(M)$ may not converge if $\|I -M \| > 1$.

Comment: A link for derivative *with respect to a matrix* may be useful.

Comment: If by derivative you mean the Fréchet derivative of a matrix function, then Theorem 3.1 of [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.219.1056&rep=rep1&type=pdf) can be used to compute it using the power series of log.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. So to my understanding, the answer is, we can calculate Fréchet derivative of $\log(M)$, or when ||I-M||<1, the normal derivative of $\log(M)$ converge, which is $M^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2):

The derivative of $\log(x)$ is $1/x$.  The derivative of the power series
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty (1-x)^n/n$$ is $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (1-x)^{n-1}$$ which converges to $x^{-1}$ if $|x| < 1$.
The matrix power series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (I-M)^{n-1}$$ converges to $M^{-1}$ if the spectral radius of $I-M$ is less than $1$.

However, caution is needed with the notion of "derivative" of a matrix valued function.  The basic problem is that matrices don't always commute.  You can't say that the derivative of $f(M)$ will be, e.g.
$$ \lim_{A \to 0} (f(M+A) - f(M)) A^{-1}$$
For example, if $f(M) = M^2$, $$(f(M+A) - f(M)) A^{-1} = M + A M A^{-1} + A$$
and as $A \to 0$, $A M A^{-1}$ need not converge to anything in particular; it can do all sorts of strange things.